# How can my .Net Core application use session variables from another application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, session-variables

My .Net Core application needs to use session variables set in another application (a WebForms app). Here is how it is configured in that WebForms application:

```
    <sessionState mode="SQLServer" sqlConnectionString="data source=.;UID=SessionStateUser;Password=somepassword;Connect Timeout=15;" timeout="20" />
```

[image]

What can I do to access session variables from my .Net Core application?

Comment: You probably can’t do that without *a lot* of work. If you want to share data between the two applications, you probably build some new independent store, so that you don’t have to bend an existing concept around into some direction it wasn’t meant for.

Comment: @poke I updated my question. You can see that the store exists.

Comment: My point is that if you are using some concept that is designed for WebForms, then you will have a hard time making that work in ASP.NET Core. The same is true with the other direction. If you instead create something on your own, you can design it in a way that makes it easy to consume from both applications.

Comment: @poke I share those session variables with asp.net MVC 5 application, so I thought it might be possible with .Net Core also...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not exactly your situation, but I was able to get a separate web application to access session data (stored in SQL Server) from my ASP.NET Core web app.

In ASP.NET Core, when backed by SQL Server, the session is stored in a table with Column ID and Column Value.
ID is the session ID and the Value is the session data.

The session id is stored as an encrypted value in a cookie called .AspNetCore.Session.
In my separate web app, I retrieved the value of this cookie, unprotected/unencrypted it, then leveraged some of the open-source asp.net core code (especially IDistributedCache) to load the session data using the unencrypted key.

It was all pretty complicated, and I'm pretty scared about having to upgrade some of the code I extracted (although it wasn't too much code).

So, it's a similar situation and it was doable. But only did it as a last resort and I would try to find a different solution if possible

Maybe this gives you some ideas though...